# Openstack havana shows only one computer

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have 3 computers with wich i want to build a cloud.
On the first i have installed MAAS, after that i have added the other two as nodes in the MAAS. I have installed juju bootstrap on the second computer and deployed openstack/keystone,quantum,nova-compute etc. and the openstack-dashboard/ on the third. 
  When i login openstack-dashboard and go to  Hypervisors i see the components /cpu,ram,hdd/ only  of the third computer /the one with the openstack/ what should i do to see the resources of all computers and build virtual machines with all of them. 
Thanks and happy new year!

Comment: Should i use add unit on the second node for all components of openstack to see it in hypervisors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the bootstrap node -- machine 0 -- available for running VMs:

```
juju add-unit nova-compute --to 0
```

You can't currently use the MAAS server itself with your setup; given the limited hardware you have available, you may find it easier to use [manual provisioning](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-manual.html) to create a juju environment on without involving MAAS. But that approach won't scale up very nicely; the Right Thing to do rather depends on your future plans for the environment as well as your current situation.

Comment: Hello and thenks for the answer! The command worked. I will use only two servers and one computer - 110gb ram, 10TB HDD, 40 CPUs. Can i use them with the limitation of juju? Thanks.

Comment: If you only plan to add additional hardware rarely, the burden of installing ubuntu on each new machine yourself, and then doing an explicit `juju add-machine ssh:<user>@<host>`, will be minimal. Manual provisioning sounds like a good answer there: you can distribute your services across the two servers as you wish, without needing a separate machine for MAAS. (That is to say: one of them will have to be the juju bootstrap node, but that shouldn't use too many resources, and you can run other services on it with --to.)